# Wordpress Plugin not Work & Display on Particular Post

Tags: php, css, wordpress, clearfix

I am here for some help regarding wordpress theme or plugin issue.

My Website Url : http://www.jhakaas.net

The post which has content the plugin works properly [http://jhakaas.net/bicycle-photo-gallery/] but the plugin does not work in the post which  does not have content [http://jhakaas.net/bikes-girls/].

I dont figure out what is the problem, can anyone help me to fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unless you can provide some more technical information, this falls into the category of a customer support issue that should be handled by the plugin provider if possible.

Some useful information to know would be: *Which plugin are you using? Which Wordpress theme? What kind of troubleshooting have you already done? Be specific.*

If you cannot provide details of a more technical and detailed nature, please look for answers with the plugin provider's support team.

> (After looking at the pages you provided, I can only assume you mean
>   the **Sharaholic plugin** is the plugin which is not displaying on a
>   particular post.)
>
> Sharaholic has a thorough support page here: [Shareaholic Helpdesk](http://support.shareaholic.com/hc/en-us)
>
> A post about Related Content not showing: [Related Content is not
>   showing up on my Wordpress blog](http://support.shareaholic.com/hc/en-us/articles/202958703-Related-Content-is-not-showing-up-on-my-Wordpress-blog)
>
> An extensive troubleshooting walkthrough: [The Ultimate
>   Troubleshooting Guide](http://support.shareaholic.com/hc/en-us/articles/200470556-The-Ultimate-Troubleshooting-Guide)
>
> And a page for submitting new support requests: [Submit new
>   request](http://support.shareaholic.com/hc/en-us/requests/new)